# Show map data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geo-platform

How can I open new Map?

I did the following steps:

1. Opened QGIS
2. Add Vector layer
3. Make Mar LQAS in csv file
4. Make Mar LQAS in shp file

[image: Screenshot]

The Map is still not visible.

Comment: Your scale looks weird. Have you right-clicked a layer then Zoom to Layer?

Comment: Try right click on your layer and click "zoom on layer". It is probably not visible because you zoomed in too far (scale 175:1) or you are at the wrong coordinates.

Comment: Open up the attribute table and make sure you see rows of data.